# Swift - Add an UIView that does not overlap current Storyboard's Views

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, popup, xib

I am trying to accomplish the following task on my drawing app:

I have designed a custom UIView in a .xib file, consisting of only a 'close' button in the UIView. By default, I do not want my app to load this UIView; I would only like for it to load when I press a button on my app's main view. After the view pops up, I would like to still be able to access the other views on my app, while the pop up is still open. Particularly, I would still like to draw lines on the view I have set up as a 'canvas.' Currently, I have added three files for this custom pop up: a class file inherited from UIView called PopUpView.swift, another class file inherited from UIViewController called PopUpViewController.swift, and the .xib file.

In the main ViewController, I have the following code

```
var popUp = popUpClass()    
@IBAction func showPopUp (sender: UIButton){
    self.view.addSubview(popUp)
    }
```

However, when I click on it, the view does not show up. I am a little confused about what the flow of the code should be and was wondering if anybody could offer me assistance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I may have found my solution. I deleted my .xib file. I used a container view and on its view controller, I designed my pop up.

Answer (score 0):

An issue I encountered when I started building an app that incorporated drawing was that the canvasView when using the override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) draws the lines in the sublayers, so if you are adding any views to the canvas, you will no longer be able to see what you draw. So if you want to add any subviews, add it to a view that is beneath the canvas view and always make sure the canvas view is on top with a clear background color.

Comment: Yes, this is a great suggestion!